# How to limit items per row with an animation?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

How can I set max items per row in the flex items below? I want to make 4 items per row with animation:

```css
.grid-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.cell-item {
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.cell-item a {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
.cell-item:hover {
  -webkit-box-flex: 4;
  -ms-flex-positive: 4;
  flex-grow: 4;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-items">

  <div class="cell-item">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cell-item">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cell-item">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cell-item">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="cell-item">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cell-item">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cell-item">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="cell-item">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

If I add 25% to the flex items, the animation won't work:

```
.cell-item {
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1 25%;
  -ms-flex: 1 25%;
  flex: 1 25%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lwbmpvcb/2/

Comment: @Liamm12 yes but not split them manually into two groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you have 2 posibilities.

1 - Add an spacer element to force the separation. If your maximum number of elements is 12, then you can use pseudo elements for this (since you have only 2 pseudos available, you can set up to 3 rows)

```css
.grid-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.cell-item {
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  flex: 1;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cell-item:hover {
  flex-grow: 4;
}
.spacer {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-items">
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
</div>
```

A slight variation about this is to have the spacers later in the DOM, and set them to the place where they belong with *order*. The advantage of this approach is if you want the number of items per row to change via media queries

```css
.grid-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.cell-item {
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cell-item:hover {
  flex-grow: 4;
}
.spacer {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order: 99;
}

.cell-item:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+4) {
    order: 1;
    background-color: tomato;
}
.cell-item:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+9) {
    order: 3;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.spacer:nth-last-child(1) {
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-items">
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="cell-item">
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer! thank you. My quick solution is to split the items into two groups.